# Is there a way to decline Mountain Lion updates?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

In particular, I receive update notifications for printer drivers where my current drivers work and I don't want to update them. I'd like to clear the updates from the store and stop receiving notifications about them.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide them - right click on the listing in the App Store updates (or purchases) list. You can unhide them by logging in to your account.

Comment: Hiding purchases does not suppress the update notification. These updates also don't appear as purchases since they patch the OS and are updates and not purchases in the first place.

Comment: right click on the listing in the App Store updates... list

Comment: Yeah thanks for the suggestion, which I have done, but as @bmike said, the problem is that next time around these keep popping up. Any other thoughts?